# Excel Macro to change control drop down option

Tags: excel, vba

I want to reset the value of this drop down menu to "USD" when I run a macro. However, as this is not a normal down down box, the following script will not work:

```
'Reset Currency to USD  (DOES NOT WORK)
Range("D1").Value = "USD"
```

[image]

Comment: Help us to help you - **Post your current code.**

Comment: That looks like a form control. Do you know how to find the name of the dropdown?

Comment: @Gary'sStudent: Current code is there in the post.

Comment: Yes, it is a form control. It is called Drop Down 11. Any ideas on how to set the value to USD?

Comment: What is the cell link for this control? Is it `D1`?

Comment: Yes, the control in located in Cell `D1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are changing the linked cell's value. However, the linked cell stores *index* (i.e. 1, 2, 3), not the *value*.

Try changing the index instead:

```
Range("D1").Value = 1
```

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct! The form control was actually linked to `=$E$109` so I just changed the code to 
`Range("E109").Value = "1" `

USD is the first Index in the list. Thank you so much for your help! Saved me a lot of further head scratching!